# What's the best approach to simulate the behavior of a form submit with a jQuery click and post event

Tags: javascript, php, html

My intention is to start a download from a server using a `js/php` approach with jQuerys [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and [`post`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) events. The problem is, that the download window isn't starting up properly like the same implementation with a trivial form submit. I think what it's missing is the action attribute, so no redirection to my `php` file is excuted.

This example works like it should:

```
<!--  A hidden form to send POST parameters to the downloader.php -->
<form style="display: hidden" action="php/result_downloader.php" method="POST" class="form_downloader">
  <input type="hidden" class="parameter1" name="timespan" value="daily"/>
  <input type="hidden" class="parameter2" name="loggedInUser" value="admin"/>
</form>

$('.downloader img').click(function(){
  $('.form_downloader').submit();
});
```

But if I implement it with plain `js` it doesn't seem to work (The download window doesn't pop up):

```
$('.downloader img').click(function(){

    $.post( "php/result_downloader.php", {

        timespan: "daily", 
        loggedInUser: "admin" } )

    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
    alert(error)
});
```

I think the problem is that no action takes place or this default? behavior gets prevented. So I want to know how to exactly simulate this submit-form event, that the download window shows up, because I think thats not the best programming practice to do it over a static hidden html form. In addition I want to send the parameter values dynamically so the static html approach is a bit hacky in my opinion.

Comment: The difference is that in the first instance when you fire submit event the post request is fired by the browser like a normal form submit. in second instance it is via ajax. First case response is handled by browser. Second case response will come back to your ajax callback. It is up to you what you do with it.

Comment: You should run `$('#form_id').submit(function(ev){ /* $.post() here */; ev.preventDefault(); });` instead of using click. `EventObject.preventDefault()` prevents normal form submission. You also have no success or done function on your `$.post()`.

Comment: @PHPglue I don't want to use a form or a submit. I want to do it with plain js and hence post the parameters dynamically via $.post but simulate the submit action in the click event.

Comment: @JissJanardhanan And whats now the best manner to do implement this two events in plain js? i dont want to use that hidden form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the scout of a fitting solution a found a [`redirect`](https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect) plugin. Using it, it's possible to simulate the forms submit with a simple 3 line `js` code:

```
  $('.downloader img').click(function(){
   $.redirect("php/result_downloader.php",{ timespan: "daily", loggedInUser: "admin"}); 
  });
 }
```

Concerning the approach of the plugin, it's the same manner like the hidden form does (first example in the question) with about 150 lines of more `js` code in the background. The form is just dynamically created and not static. But overall it's not a bad solution for more convenience and code readability if you have more then one download button.